# Event listeners for a UITextArea ios

Tags: ios, ios5

I have been trying in vain to try to find how to add listeners to text area.

What I am basically trying to do is create a rich text editor where I can let the user comment on a particular item.

For this purpose I am using a text area. If you have any other suggestion please let me know.

On another note, I have not seen that there is text did change or related functionality for the textarea. Is there a way we can build it ourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for are the `UITextViewDelegate`'s. Have a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html

EDIT

Per our chat the tutorial you are looking for to also ad a done button above your keyboard can be found at http://gabriel-tips.blogspot.com/2011/05/input-accessory-view-how-to-add-extra.html

Comment: This work fine for all the events but I am not able to resign first responder on didEndEditing event

Comment: The use `resignFirstResponder`

Comment: in which event should i include the resignFirstResponder was what I meant to ask .

Comment: Do you have a done button at the top of the keyboard? How are you wanting to dismiss it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15684/discussion-between-shrek-and-bot)